# Kendo UI MVC Grid popup editor close event removing grid state

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a **Keno UI MVC grid**, I have created a `ClientTemplate` for check box field.
On check box click event I am adding class to the **tr** as selected. and opening popup editor for that row details.

When I close the pop up window, check box will get unchecked and selected row is becoming unselected. How can i prevent that and maintain the state.

OnClick event of checkbox

```
function chkClick(e) {
    isChecked = $(e).is(':checked');
    _addressId = $(e).val();


    var $tr = $(e).closest("tr");

    if (isChecked) {
        $tr.addClass("k-state-selected");
        $tr.find(".k-grid-edit").click();
    }
    else {
        $tr.removeClass("k-state-selected");
        $tr.find(".k-grid-cancel").click();
    }
}
```

OnEdit event of the Grid row

```
function onEdit(e) {

    e.container.data("kendoWindow").bind("close", function () {
        if (_addressId > 0) {
            var grid = $('#practiceLocationsGrid').data().kendoGrid;

            var dataItem = grid.dataSource.get(_addressId);

            dataItem.set('selected', isChecked);

        }
    })

}
```

**Before Clicking the check box**
[image]

**After clicking the checkbox**
[image]

**After closing the edit popup (as you can see after I close the window the row that is selected is getting un-selected and check box is going un-checked)**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create on change event. selectable true and write the open window function in the onchange event.

```
  template: "<input name='fullyPaid' class='ob-paid' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: fullyPaid' #= fullyPaid ? checked='checked' : '' #/>"
 }
  ]
});


var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.tbody.on("change", ".ob-paid", function (e) {

// open the window. 
});
```

Check Here

http://jsbin.com/ebadaj/12/edit

Comment: I don't understand your answer it doesn't sound close to my question. my problem is not opening the window. It is after I close the window the row that is selected is getting un-selected and check box is going un-checked